# Same jinja templated sls file complies on one host but fails to compile on another

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following SLS file in which I'm trying to centralize static routing on minions:

mpls_routing.sls:

```
{% for interface in grains.get('ip_interfaces') %}
{% if interface != 'lo' %}

interface-{{interface}}:
  file:
    - name: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-{{interface}}
    - managed
    - source: salt://mpls_routing/mpls_routes.cfg

NetworkManager:
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-{{interface}}
    - require:
      - interface-{{interface}}

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}`
```

When I attempt to compile this SLS file using state.show_sls mpls_routing the file compiles fine on one minion and fails on the another.

```
salt -v -L 'minion1,minon2' state.show_sls mpls_routing

minion1:
    ----------
    NetworkManager:
        ----------
        __env__:
            base
        __sls__:
            mpls_routing
        service:
            |_
              ----------
              enable:
                  True
            |_
              ----------
              reload:
                  True
            |_
              ----------
              watch:
                  |_
                    ----------
                    file:
                        /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens192
            |_
              ----------
              require:
                  - interface-ens192
            - running
            |_
              ----------
              order:
                  10001
    interface-ens192:
        ----------
        __env__:
            base
        __sls__:
            mpls_routing
        file:
            |_
              ----------
              name:
                  /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens192
            - managed
            |_
              ----------
              source:
                  salt://mpls_routing/mpls_routes.cfg
            |_
              ----------
              order:
                  10000
minion2:
    - Rendering SLS 'base:mpls_routing' failed: while constructing a mapping
        in "<unicode string>", line 6, column 1:
          interface-ens192:
          ^
      found conflicting ID 'NetworkManager'
        in "<unicode string>", line 31, column 1:
          NetworkManager:
          ^
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

I'm not sure why this is failing on the second minion. The name of the interface in the error shows that the jinja template is getting the interface name correct. The sls fails to compile even when salt is targeting just minion2. I'm not sure what's going on here or how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please show which interface(s) both minions have?

Comment: minion1 above:     ip_interfaces:
        ----------
        ens192:
            - 172.20.1.17
            - fe80::250:56ff:fea2:53c4
        lo:
            - 127.0.0.1
            - ::1
minion2:    ip_interfaces:
        ----------
        ens192:
            - 172.20.0.12
            - fe80::250:56ff:fea2:2645
        ens224:
        lo:
            - 127.0.0.1
            - ::1

Comment: Gijs you nailed it. The second interface on minion two was generating a second map entry for NetworkManager. Changing the sls to NetworkManager-{{interface}}:

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after Gijs's comment above led me to it. The second object in the sls file

```
NetworkManager:
```

Was being repeated on minion2 which has multiple ip_interface values returned by grains. This meant that the sls had two copies of the same dictionary key. I updated the sls file to:

```
{% for interface in grains.get('ip_interfaces') %}
{% if interface != 'lo' %}

interface-{{interface}}:
  file:
    - name: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-{{interface}}
    - managed
    - source: salt://mpls_routing/mpls_routes.cfg

NetworkManager-{{interface}}:
  service.running:
    - name: NetworkManager
    - enable: True
    - reload: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-{{interface}}
    - require:
      - interface-{{interface}}

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Which fixed the issue.